# Train and valid accuracy and loss stay the same over many epochs of training with Pytorch

Tags: python, cnn, computer-vision, pytorch

I am building a neural network to recognize hand gestures from the leapGestRecog data set from Kaggle. While training I ran into some issues.

Here are some images of my data set:
[image]

I augmented my data by adding the mirror version of each image with the corresponding label. Each image is 120x320 pixels, grayscale and my batch size is around 100 (my memory does not allow me to have more). I am using pytorch, and I have split the data into 24000 images on the training, 10 000 on the validation and 6000 on the test sets. The model which I have built looks as follows:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,input_size=32, hidden_size=64,n_classes=10):
        """ Define our model """
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,input_size, kernel_size=(3,3),stride=(1,1),padding=1)
        self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(input_size,hidden_size,kernel_size=(3,3),padding=1)
        self.relu2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxp2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(hidden_size,128,kernel_size=3,padding=1)
        self.maxp3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2))
        self.l1    = nn.Linear(128 * 15 * 40,128)
        self.relul = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.l2    = nn.Linear(128,n_classes)
        self.soft  = nn.Softmax(1)


    def forward(self, x):
        """ The forward pass of our model """
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.relu1(x)
        x = self.maxp1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.maxp2(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.maxp3(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0),-1)
        x = self.l1(x)
        x = self.relu2(x)
        x = self.l2(x)
        x = self.relul(x)
        x = self.soft(x)
        return x
```

The training procedure is quite standard for a pytorch neural network.

```py
def train_model(model,train_data,valid_data,learning_rate,num_epochs,optimizer,criterion):
    """ Training procedure of the model together with accuracy and loss for both data sets """
    train_loss = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    valid_loss = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    train_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    valid_accuracy = np.zeros(num_epochs)
    
    """begin training"""
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_losses = []
        train_correct= 0
        total_items  = 0

        valid_losses = []
        valid_correct = 0

        for images,labels in train_data:

            images = images.float()
            labels = labels.long()
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            """add to GPU hopefully"""
            images = images.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            """Forward pass"""
            outputs = model.forward(images)
            loss    = criterion(outputs,labels)

            """Backward pass"""
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            """staticstics"""
            train_losses.append(loss.item())
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data,1)
            train_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            total_items += labels.size(0)

        train_loss[epoch] = np.mean(train_losses)
        train_accuracy[epoch] = (1 * train_correct/total_items)

        with torch.no_grad():
            correct_val = 0
            total_val = 0

            for images,labels in valid_data:

                images = images.float()
                labels = labels.long()

                images = images.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                outputs = model.forward(images)
                loss    = criterion(outputs, labels)

                valid_losses.append(loss.item())
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)

                correct_val += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
                total_val   += labels.size(0)

        valid_loss[epoch] = np.mean(valid_losses)
        valid_accuracy[epoch] = (1 * correct_val/total_val)

        print("Epoch: [{},{}], train accuracy: {:.4f}, valid accuracy: {:.4f}, train loss: {:.4f}, valid loss: {:.4f}"
        .format(num_epochs,epoch+1,train_accuracy[epoch],valid_accuracy[epoch],train_loss[epoch],valid_accuracy[epoch]))

    return model, train_accuracy, train_loss, valid_accuracy, valid_loss
```

And this is how I call the train function.

```py
network = Model()
network = network.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(network.parameters(),lr=0.01,momentum=0.9)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model, train_accuracy, train_loss, valid_accuracy, valid_loss = train_model(model=network,train_data=train,valid_data=valid,learning_rate=0.01,num_epochs=100,optimizer=optimizer,criterion=criterion)

print("Ready")
```

Now, no matter what I do my train loss and accuracy as well as my validation loss and accuracy always stays the same.

```
Epoch: [100,1], train accuracy: 0.0999, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3612, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,2], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,3], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,4], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,5], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,6], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,7], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,8], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,9], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,10], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,11], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
Epoch: [100,12], train accuracy: 0.1000, valid accuracy: 0.1050, train loss: 2.3611, valid loss: 0.1050
```

Perhaps I am underfitting, to prevent that I increased the model's complexity, I also tried changing the learning rate from 0.001 to 0.01 etc but no matter what I tried I could not fix it. Does someone know what is going wrong and even more importantly can someone help me fix it?

Comment: It appears that you call model.forward(data) instead of just model(data).